# 1 result set from 3 queries?

Tags: oracle, join

I'm at my wits end attempting to make this happen. Currently I have 3 separate queries. For automation purposes I need to get the results of these three queries in one output, I cannot seem to join them properly to get the expected results.

QUERY 1:

```
SELECT OH.EXTN_HOST_ORDER_REF,
       OL.EXTN_HOST_ORDER_LINE_REF,
       OL.ORIGINAL_ORDERED_QTY,
       OL.EXTN_TENDER_QUANTITY,
       OL.EXTN_CUM_PICK_QTY,
       OL.SHIPPED_QUANTITY,
       OL.EXTN_REFUND_QTY
FROM   YFS_ORDER_HEADER OH,
       YFS_ORDER_LINE OL
WHERE  OH.ORDER_HEADER_KEY = OL.ORDER_HEADER_KEY
       AND OH.DOCUMENT_TYPE = '0001'
       AND OH.EXTN_HOST_ORDER_REF = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
ORDER  BY PL.EXTN_HOST_ORDER_LINE_REF ASC;
```

QUERY 2:

```
SELECT RS.STATUS_QUANTITY AS RETURNED_QTY
FROM   YFS_ORDER_HEADER OH,
       YFS_ORDER_LINE OL,
       YFS_ORDER_RELEASE_STATUS RS
WHERE  OH.ORDER_HEADER_KEY = OL.ORDER_HEADER_KEY
       AND OL.ORDER_LINE_KEY = RS.ORDER_LINE_KEY
       AND RS.STATUS = '3700.02'
       AND OH.EXTN_HOST_ORDER_REF = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
```

QUERY 3

```
SELECT RS.STATUS_QUANTITY AS CANCELLED_QTY
FROM   YFS_ORDER_HEADER OH,
       YFS_ORDER_LINE OL,
       YFS_ORDER_RELEASE_STATUS RS
WHERE  OH.ORDER_HEADER_KEY = OL.ORDER_HEADER_KEY
       AND OL.ORDER_LINE_KEY = RS.ORDER_LINE_KEY
       AND RS.STATUS = '9000'
       AND OH.EXTN_HOST_ORDER_REF = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
```

The query should show NULL values where no data exists from query 2 & 3.

Thanks in advance for your help and advice!

Comment: Thank You Martin Smith for editing. You beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to show both returned and cancelled quantities, the following simple edit should work. Hope this helps.

```
  SELECT oh.extn_host_order_ref,
         ol.extn_host_order_line_ref,
         ol.original_ordered_qty,
         ol.extn_tender_quantity,
         ol.extn_cum_pick_qty,
         ol.shipped_quantity,
         ol.extn_refund_qty,
         DECODE (rs.status, '3700.02', rs.status_quantity) AS returned_qty,
         DECODE (rs.status, '9000', rs.status_quantity) AS cancelled_qty
    FROM yfs_order_header oh
         INNER JOIN yfs_order_line ol
            ON oh.order_header_key = ol.order_header_key
         LEFT OUTER JOIN yfs_order_release_status rs
            ON ol.order_line_key = rs.order_line_key
   WHERE oh.document_type = '0001' AND oh.extn_host_order_ref = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
ORDER BY pl.extn_host_order_line_ref ASC;
```